# Use objects from constructor in other methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my Laravel App I have several objects (user, products, ...) that I need in all methods within my controller.

Instead of getting the object from the model in every method I would like to get it once in the constructor and then use it.

How can I do this? I tried it and unless I save values in a SESSION they are not available outside the contructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save them as properties of the object:

```
class MyClass {

  private $user;

  public function __construct(){
    // load your objects here
    $this->user = User::find(1);
  }

  public function someFunction(){
    // use the objects here
    echo $this->user->name;
  }
}
```